# Why is this code giving error instead of giving binary number?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if my question sound silly but I am new to coding and trying to learn javascript. In one of the exercises on edabit, I am supposed to convert a decimal into binary. Here is the code I have written but it's not yielding the desired output. Where am I making a mistake in the code?

```
function binary(decimal) {
    var arr = [];
    var remainderX;
    while (decimal > 0) {
        remainderX = decimal % 2;
        decimal = decimal / 2;
        arr.unshift(remainderX);
    }
    return arr.join('');
}
```

Here is the error I get upon executing the code.

```
FAILED: Expected: '1100100', instead got: '5e-3241e-3231.5e-3233e-3236e-3231.24e-3222.47e-3224.94e-3229.9e-3221.976e-3213.953e-3217.905e-3211.581e-3203.162e-3206.324e-3201.2648e-3192.5296e-3195.05923e-3191.011846e-3182.023693e-3184.047386e-3188.09477e-3181.6189543e-3173.2379086e-3176.475817e-3171.29516345e-3162.5903269e-3165.1806538e-3161.036130757e-3152.072261515e-3154.14452303e-3158.28904606e-3151.6578092117e-3143.3156184234e-3146.631236847e-3141.32624736935e-3132.6524947387e-3135.3049894774e-3131.060997895483e-3122.121995790965e-3124.24399158193e-3128.48798316386e-3121.697596632772e-3113.3951932655444e-3116.790386531089e-3111.35807730621777e-3102.71615461243555e-3105.4323092248711e-3101.08646184497422e-3092.17292368994844e-3094.34584737989688e-3098.691694759793755e-3091.738338951958751e-3083.476677903917502e-3086.953355807835004e-3081.3906711615670009e-3072.7813423231340017e-3075.5626846462680035e-3071.1125369292536007e-3062.2250738585072014e-3064.450147717014403e-3068.900295434028806e-3061.780059086805761e-3053.560118173611522e-3057.120236347223044e-3051.4240472694446089e-3042.8480945388892178e-3045.6961890777784355e-3041.1392378155556871e-3032.2784756311113742e-3034.5569512622227484e-3039.113902524445497e-3031.8227805048890994e-3023.645561009778199e-3027.291122019556397e-3021.4582244039112795e-3012.916448807822559e-3015.832897615645118e-3011.1665795231290236e-3002.3331590462580472e-3004.6663180925160944e-3009.332636185032189e-3001.8665272370064378e-2993.7330544740128755e-2997.466108948025751e-2991.4932217896051502e-2982.9864435792103004e-2985.972887158420601e-2981.1945774316841202e-2972.3891548633682403e-2974.7783097267364807e-2979.556619453472961e-2971.9113238906945923e-2963.8226477813891845e-2967.645295562778369e-2961.5290591125556738e-2953.0581182251113476e-2956.116236450222695e-2951.223247290044539e-2942.446494580089078e-2944.892989160178156e-2949.785978320356312e-2941.9571956640712625e-2933.914391328142525e-2937.82878265628505e-2931.56575653125701e-2923.13151306251402e-2926.26302612502804e-2921.252605225005608e-2912.505210450011216e-2915.010420900022432e-2911.0020841800044864e-2902.0041683600089728e-2904.0083367200179456e-2908.016673440035891e-2901.6033346880071782e-2893.2066693760143564e-2896.413338752028713e-2891.2826677504057426e-2882.565335500811485e-2885.13067100162297e-2881.026134200324594e-2872.052268400649188e-2874.104536801298376e-2878.209073602596752e-2871.6418147205193505e-2863.283629441038701e-2866.567258882077402e-2861.3134517764154804e-2852.6269035528309608e-2855.2538071056619216e-2851.0507614211323843e-2842.1015228422647686e-2844.203045684529537e-2848.406091369059075e-2841.681218273811815e-2833.36243654762363e-2836.72487309524726e-2831.344974619049452e-2822.689949238098904e-2825.379898476197808e-2821.0759796952395615e-2812.151959390479123e-2814.303918780958246e-2818.607837561916492e-2811.7215675123832985e-2803.443135024766597e-2806.886270049533194e-2801.3772540099066388e-2792.7545080198132776e-2795.509016039626555e-2791.101803207925311e-2782.203606415850622e-2784.407212831701244e-2788.814425663402488e-2781.7628851326804976e-2773.5257702653609953e-2777.051540530721991e-2771.4103081061443981e-2762.8206162122887962e-2765.6412324245775924e-2761.1282464849155185e-2752.256492969831037e-2754.512985939662074e-2759.025971879324148e-2751.8051943758648296e-2743.610388751729659e-2747.220777503459318e-2741.4441555006918637e-2732.8883110013837273e-2735.776622002767455e-2731.155324400553491e-2722.310648801106982e-2724.621297602213964e-2729.242595204427927e-2721.8485190408855855e-2713.697038081771171e-2717.394076163542342e-2711.4788152327084684e-2702.9576304654169368e-2705.9152609308338736e-2701.1830521861667747e-2692.3661043723335494e-2694.732208744667099e-2699.464417489334198e-2691.8928834978668395e-2683.785766995733679e-2687.571533991467358e-2681.5143067982934716e-2673.0286135965869433e-2676.0572271931738865e-2671.2114454386347773e-2662.4228908772695546e-2664.845781754539109e-2669.691563509078218e-2661.9383127018156437e-2653.8766254036312874e-2657.753250807262575e-2651.550650161452515e-2643.10130032290503e-2646.20260064581006e-2641.240520129162012e-2632.481040258324024e-2634.962080516648048e-2639.924161033296096e-2631.984832206659219e-2623.969664413318438e-2627.939328826636877e-2621.5878657653273753e-2613.1757315306547506e-2616.351463061309501e-2611.2702926122619002e-2602.5405852245238005e-2605.081170449047601e-2601.0162340898095202e-2592.0324681796190404e-2594.064936359238081e-2598.129872718476162e-2591.6259745436952323e-2583.2519490873904646e-2586.503898174780929e-2581.3007796349561859e-2572.6015592699123717e-2575.2031185398247434e-2571.0406237079649487e-2562.0812474159298974e-2564.162494831859795e-2568.32498966371959e-2561.664997932743918e-2553.329995865487836e-2556.659991730975672e-2551.3319983461951343e-2542.6639966923902686e-2545.327993384780537e-2541.0655986769561075e-2532.131197353912215e-2534.26239470782443e-2538.52478941564886e-2531.704957883129772e-2523.409915766259544e-2526.819831532519088e-2521.3639663065038175e-2512.727932613007635e-2515.45586522601527e-2511.091173045203054e-2502.182346090406108e-2504.364692180812216e-2508.729384361624432e-2501.7458768723248864e-2493.491753744649773e-2496.983507489299546e-2491.3967014978599092e-2482.7934029957198183e-2485.586805991439637e-2481.1173611982879273e-2472.2347223965758547e-2474.469444793151709e-2478.938889586303419e-2471.7877779172606837e-2463.5755558345213674e-2467.151111669042735e-2461.430222333808547e-2452.860444667617094e-2455.720889335234188e-2451.1441778670468376e-2442.2883557340936752e-2444.5767114681873503e-2449.153422936374701e-2441.8306845872749401e-2433.6613691745498803e-2437.322738349099761e-2431.4645476698199521e-2422.9290953396399042e-2425.8581906792798084e-2421.1716381358559617e-2412.3432762717119234e-2414.686552543423847e-2419.373105086847693e-2411.8746210173695387e-2403.7492420347390774e-2407.498484069478155e-2401.499696813895631e-2392.999393627791262e-2395.998787255582524e-2391.1997574511165048e-2382.3995149022330095e-2384.799029804466019e-2389.598059608932038e-2381.9196119217864076e-2373.839223843572815e-2377.67844768714563e-2371.535689537429126e-2363.071379074858252e-2366.142758149716504e-2361.2285516299433009e-2352.4571032598866018e-2354.9142065197732035e-2359.828413039546407e-2351.9656826079092814e-2343.931365215818563e-2347.862730431637126e-2341.5725460863274251e-2333.1450921726548502e-2336.2901843453097005e-2331.2580368690619401e-2322.5160737381238802e-2325.0321474762477604e-2321.0064294952495521e-2312.0128589904991042e-2314.0257179809982083e-2318.051435961996417e-2311.6102871923992833e-2303.2205743847985667e-2306.441148769597133e-2301.2882297539194267e-2292.5764595078388533e-2295.152919015677707e-2291.0305838031355413e-2282.0611676062710827e-2284.1223352125421653e-2288.244670425084331e-2281.6489340850168661e-2273.2978681700337323e-2276.5957363400674645e-2271.3191472680134929e-2262.6382945360269858e-2265.2765890720539716e-2261.0553178144107943e-2252.1106356288215886e-2254.221271257643177e-2258.442542515286355e-2251.688508503057271e-2243.377017006114542e-2246.754034012229084e-2241.3508068024458167e-2232.7016136048916335e-2235.403227209783267e-2231.0806454419566534e-2222.1612908839133068e-2224.3225817678266135e-2228.645163535653227e-2221.7290327071306454e-2213.458065414261291e-2216.916130828522582e-2211.3832261657045163e-2202.7664523314090327e-2205.532904662818065e-2201.106580932563613e-2192.213161865127226e-2194.426323730254452e-2198.852647460508905e-2191.770529492101781e-2183.541058984203562e-2187.082117968407124e-2181.4164235936814247e-2172.8328471873628494e-2175.665694374725699e-2171.1331388749451398e-2162.2662777498902796e-2164.532555499780559e-2169.065110999561118e-2161.8130221999122236e-2153.6260443998244473e-2157.252088799648895e-2151.450417759929779e-2142.900835519859558e-2145.801671039719116e-2141.1603342079438231e-2132.3206684158876463e-2134.6413368317752925e-2139.282673663550585e-2131.856534732710117e-2123.713069465420234e-2127.426138930840468e-2121.4852277861680936e-2112.9704555723361872e-2115.9409111446723744e-2111.1881822289344749e-2102.3763644578689498e-2104.7527289157378996e-2109.505457831475799e-2101.9010915662951598e-2093.8021831325903196e-2097.604366265180639e-2091.5208732530361279e-2083.0417465060722557e-2086.0834930121445114e-2081.2166986024289023e-2072.4333972048578046e-2074.866794409715609e-2079.733588819431218e-2071.9467177638862437e-2063.8934355277724873e-2067.786871055544975e-2061.557374211108995e-2053.11474842221799e-2056.22949684443598e-2051.245899368887196e-2042.491798737774392e-2044.983597475548784e-2049.967194951097568e-2041.9934389902195135e-2033.986877980439027e-2037.973755960878054e-2031.5947511921756108e-2023.1895023843512216e-2026.379004768702443e-2021.2758009537404886e-2012.5516019074809773e-2015.1032038149619546e-2011.0206407629923909e-2002.0412815259847818e-2004.0825630519695637e-2008.165126103939127e-2001.6330252207878255e-1993.266050441575651e-1996.532100883151302e-1991.3064201766302604e-1982.6128403532605207e-1985.2256807065210415e-1981.0451361413042083e-1972.0902722826084166e-1974.180544565216833e-1978.361089130433666e-1971.6722178260867333e-1963.3444356521734666e-1966.688871304346933e-1961.3377742608693866e-1952.6755485217387732e-1955.3510970434775465e-1951.0702194086955093e-1942.1404388173910186e-1944.280877634782037e-1948.561755269564074e-1941.7123510539128149e-1933.4247021078256297e-1936.8494042156512595e-1931.3698808431302519e-1922.7397616862605038e-1925.4795233725210076e-1921.0959046745042015e-1912.191809349008403e-1914.383618698016806e-1918.767237396033612e-1911.7534474792067224e-1903.506894958413445e-1907.01378991682689e-1901.402757983365378e-1892.805515966730756e-1895.611031933461512e-1891.1222063866923024e-1882.2444127733846047e-1884.4888255467692094e-1888.977651093538419e-1881.7955302187076838e-1873.5910604374153675e-1877.182120874830735e-1871.436424174966147e-1862.872848349932294e-1865.745696699864588e-1861.1491393399729176e-1852.2982786799458352e-1854.5965573598916705e-1859.193114719783341e-1851.8386229439566682e-1843.6772458879133364e-1847.354491775826673e-1841.4708983551653345e-1832.941796710330669e-1835.883593420661338e-1831.1767186841322676e-1822.3534373682645353e-1824.7068747365290705e-1829.413749473058141e-1821.8827498946116282e-1813.7654997892232564e-1817.530999578446513e-1811.5061999156893026e-1803.012399831378605e-1806.02479966275721e-1801.204959932551442e-1792.409919865102884e-1794.819839730205768e-1799.639679460411536e-1791.9279358920823073e-1783.8558717841646146e-1787.711743568329229e-1781.5423487136658458e-1773.0846974273316917e-1776.169394854663383e-1771.2338789709326767e-1762.4677579418653533e-1764.935515883730707e-1769.871031767461413e-1761.9742063534922827e-1753.9484127069845653e-1757.896825413969131e-1751.5793650827938261e-1743.1587301655876523e-1746.3174603311753045e-1741.2634920662350609e-1732.5269841324701218e-1735.0539682649402436e-1731.0107936529880487e-1722.0215873059760975e-1724.043174611952195e-1728.08634922390439e-1721.617269844780878e-1713.234539689561756e-1716.469079379123512e-1711.2938158758247024e-1702.5876317516494047e-1705.1752635032988095e-1701.0350527006597619e-1692.0701054013195238e-1694.1402108026390476e-1698.280421605278095e-1691.656084321055619e-1683.312168642111238e-1686.624337284222476e-1681.3248674568444952e-1672.6497349136889905e-1675.299469827377981e-1671.0598939654755962e-1662.1197879309511924e-1664.239575861902385e-1668.47915172380477e-1661.695830344760954e-1653.391660689521908e-1656.783321379043816e-1651.3566642758087631e-1642.7133285516175262e-1645.4266571032350524e-1641.0853314206470105e-1632.170662841294021e-1634.341325682588042e-1638.682651365176084e-1631.7365302730352168e-1623.4730605460704336e-1626.946121092140867e-1621.3892242184281734e-1612.778448436856347e-1615.556896873712694e-1611.1113793747425387e-1602.2227587494850775e-1604.445517498970155e-1608.89103499794031e-1601.778206999588062e-1593.556413999176124e-1597.112827998352248e-1591.4225655996704496e-1582.845131199340899e-1585.690262398681798e-1581.1380524797363597e-1572.2761049594727193e-1574.552209918945439e-1579.104419837890877e-1571.8208839675781755e-1563.641767935156351e-1567.283535870312702e-1561.4567071740625404e-1552.9134143481250808e-1555.8268286962501615e-1551.1653657392500323e-1542.3307314785000646e-1544.661462957000129e-1549.322925914000258e-1541.8645851828000517e-1533.7291703656001034e-1537.458340731200207e-1531.4916681462400413e-1522.9833362924800827e-1525.966672584960165e-1521.193334516992033e-1512.386669033984066e-1514.773338067968132e-1519.546676135936265e-1511.909335227187253e-1503.818670454374506e-1507.637340908749012e-1501.5274681817498023e-1493.0549363634996047e-1496.109872726999209e-1491.2219745453998419e-1482.4439490907996837e-1484.8878981815993675e-1489.775796363198735e-1481.955159272639747e-1473.910318545279494e-1477.820637090558988e-1471.5641274181117976e-1463.128254836223595e-1466.25650967244719e-1461.251301934489438e-1452.502603868978876e-1455.005207737957752e-1451.0010415475915505e-1442.002083095183101e-1444.004166190366202e-1448.008332380732404e-1441.6016664761464807e-1433.2033329522929615e-1436.406665904585923e-1431.2813331809171846e-1422.5626663618343692e-1425.1253327236687384e-1421.0250665447337477e-1412.0501330894674953e-1414.1002661789349907e-1418.200532357869981e-1411.6401064715739963e-1403.2802129431479926e-1406.560425886295985e-1401.312085177259197e-1392.624170354518394e-1395.248340709036788e-1391.0496681418073576e-1382.0993362836147152e-1384.1986725672294305e-1388.397345134458861e-1381.6794690268917722e-1373.3589380537835444e-1376.717876107567089e-1371.3435752215134178e-1362.6871504430268355e-1365.374300886053671e-1361.0748601772107342e-1352.1497203544214684e-1354.299440708842937e-1358.598881417685874e-1351.7197762835371747e-1343.4395525670743494e-1346.879105134148699e-1341.3758210268297398e-1332.7516420536594796e-1335.503284107318959e-1331.1006568214637918e-1322.2013136429275836e-1324.402627285855167e-1328.805254571710335e-1321.761050914342067e-1313.522101828684134e-1317.044203657368268e-1311.4088407314736535e-1302.817681462947307e-1305.635362925894614e-1301.1270725851789228e-1292.2541451703578456e-1294.508290340715691e-1299.016580681431383e-1291.8033161362862765e-1283.606632272572553e-1287.213264545145106e-1281.4426529090290212e-1272.8853058180580424e-1275.770611636116085e-1271.154122327223217e-1262.308244654446434e-1264.616489308892868e-1269.232978617785736e-1261.8465957235571472e-1253.6931914471142943e-1257.386382894228589e-1251.4772765788457177e-1242.9545531576914354e-1245.909106315382871e-1241.1818212630765742e-1232.3636425261531484e-1234.727285052306297e-1239.454570104612593e-1231.8909140209225187e-1223.7818280418450374e-1227.563656083690075e-1221.512731216738015e-1213.02546243347603e-1216.05092486695206e-1211.210184973390412e-1202.420369946780824e-1204.840739893561648e-1209.681479787123296e-1201.936295957424659e-1193.872591914849318e-1197.745183829698637e-1191.5490367659397273e-1183.0980735318794546e-1186.196147063758909e-1181.2392294127517818e-1172.4784588255035637e-1174.9569176510071274e-1179.913835302014255e-1171.982767060402851e-1163.965534120805702e-1167.931068241611404e-1161.5862136483222808e-1153.1724272966445615e-1156.344854593289123e-1151.2689709186578246e-1142.5379418373156492e-1145.0758836746312984e-1141.0151767349262597e-1132.0303534698525194e-1134.060706939705039e-1138.121413879410078e-1131.6242827758820155e-1123.248565551764031e-1126.497131103528062e-1121.2994262207056124e-1112.5988524414112248e-1115.1977048828224496e-1111.0395409765644899e-1102.0790819531289798e-1104.1581639062579597e-1108.316327812515919e-1101.6632655625031839e-1093.3265311250063677e-1096.6530622500127355e-1091.3306124500025471e-1082.6612249000050942e-1085.3224498000101884e-1081.0644899600020377e-1072.1289799200040754e-1074.257959840008151e-1078.515919680016301e-1071.7031839360032603e-1063.4063678720065206e-1066.812735744013041e-1061.3625471488026082e-1052.7250942976052165e-1055.450188595210433e-1051.0900377190420866e-1042.1800754380841732e-1044.3601508761683463e-1048.720301752336693e-1041.7440603504673385e-1033.488120700934677e-1036.976241401869354e-1031.3952482803738708e-1022.7904965607477417e-1025.580993121495483e-1021.1161986242990967e-1012.2323972485981933e-1014.4647944971963866e-1018.929588994392773e-1011.7859177988785547e-1003.5718355977571093e-1007.143671195514219e-1001.4287342391028437e-992.8574684782056875e-995.714936956411375e-991.142987391282275e-982.28597478256455e-984.5719495651291e-989.1438991302582e-981.82877982605164e-973.65755965210328e-977.31511930420656e-971.463023860841312e-962.926047721682624e-965.852095443365248e-961.1704190886730496e-952.340838177346099e-954.681676354692198e-959.363352709384397e-951.8726705418768793e-943.7453410837537587e-947.490682167507517e-941.4981364335015035e-932.996272867003007e-935.992545734006014e-931.1985091468012028e-922.3970182936024055e-924.794036587204811e-929.588073174409622e-921.9176146348819244e-913.835229269763849e-917.670458539527698e-911.5340917079055395e-903.068183415811079e-906.136366831622158e-901.2272733663244316e-892.4545467326488633e-894.9090934652977266e-899.818186930595453e-891.9636373861190906e-883.927274772238181e-887.854549544476362e-881.5709099088952725e-873.141819817790545e-876.28363963558109e-871.256727927116218e-862.513455854232436e-865.026911708464872e-861.0053823416929744e-852.0107646833859488e-854.0215293667718976e-858.043058733543795e-851.608611746708759e-843.217223493417518e-846.434446986835036e-841.2868893973670072e-832.5737787947340145e-835.147557589468029e-831.0295115178936058e-822.0590230357872116e-824.118046071574423e-828.236092143148846e-821.6472184286297693e-813.2944368572595385e-816.588873714519077e-811.3177747429038154e-802.6355494858076308e-805.2710989716152616e-801.0542197943230523e-792.1084395886461046e-794.216879177292209e-798.433758354584419e-791.6867516709168837e-783.3735033418337674e-786.747006683667535e-781.349401336733507e-772.698802673467014e-775.397605346934028e-771.0795210693868056e-762.1590421387736112e-764.3180842775472223e-768.636168555094445e-761.727233711018889e-753.454467422037778e-756.908934844075556e-751.3817869688151111e-742.7635739376302223e-745.5271478752604446e-741.1054295750520889e-732.2108591501041778e-734.4217183002083556e-738.843436600416711e-731.7686873200833423e-723.5373746401666845e-727.074749280333369e-721.4149498560666738e-712.8298997121333476e-715.659799424266695e-711.131959884853339e-702.263919769706678e-704.527839539413356e-709.055679078826712e-701.8111358157653425e-693.622271631530685e-697.24454326306137e-691.448908652612274e-682.897817305224548e-685.795634610449096e-681.1591269220898192e-672.3182538441796384e-674.636507688359277e-679.273015376718553e-671.8546030753437107e-663.7092061506874214e-667.418412301374843e-661.4836824602749686e-652.967364920549937e-655.934729841099874e-651.1869459682199748e-642.3738919364399497e-644.7477838728798994e-649.495567745759799e-641.8991135491519597e-633.7982270983039195e-637.596454196607839e-631.5192908393215678e-623.0385816786431356e-626.077163357286271e-621.2154326714572542e-612.4308653429145085e-614.861730685829017e-619.723461371658034e-611.9446922743316068e-603.8893845486632136e-607.778769097326427e-601.5557538194652854e-593.111507638930571e-596.223015277861142e-591.2446030555722283e-582.4892061111444567e-584.9784122222889134e-589.956824444577827e-581.9913648889155653e-573.9827297778311307e-577.965459555662261e-571.5930919111324523e-563.1861838222649046e-566.372367644529809e-561.2744735289059618e-552.5489470578119236e-555.097894115623847e-551.0195788231247695e-542.039157646249539e-544.078315292499078e-548.156630584998156e-541.6313261169996311e-533.2626522339992623e-536.5253044679985245e-531.3050608935997049e-522.6101217871994098e-525.2202435743988196e-521.0440487148797639e-512.0880974297595278e-514.1761948595190557e-518.352389719038111e-511.6704779438076223e-503.3409558876152446e-506.681911775230489e-501.3363823550460978e-492.6727647100921956e-495.345529420184391e-491.0691058840368783e-482.1382117680737565e-484.276423536147513e-488.552847072295026e-481.7105694144590052e-473.4211388289180104e-476.842277657836021e-471.3684555315672042e-462.7369110631344083e-465.473822126268817e-461.0947644252537633e-452.1895288505075267e-454.3790577010150533e-458.758115402030107e-451.7516230804060213e-443.5032461608120427e-447.006492321624085e-441.401298464324817e-432.802596928649634e-435.605193857299268e-431.1210387714598537e-422.2420775429197073e-424.4841550858394146e-428.968310171678829e-421.7936620343357659e-413.5873240686715317e-417.174648137343063e-411.4349296274686127e-402.8698592549372254e-405.739718509874451e-401.1479437019748901e-392.2958874039497803e-394.5917748078995606e-399.183549615799121e-391.8367099231598242e-383.6734198463196485e-387.346839692639297e-381.4693679385278594e-372.9387358770557188e-375.8774717541114375e-371.1754943508222875e-362.350988701644575e-364.70197740328915e-369.4039548065783e-361.88079096131566e-353.76158192263132e-357.52316384526264e-351.504632769052528e-343.009265538105056e-346.018531076210112e-341.2037062152420224e-332.4074124304840448e-334.8148248609680896e-339.629649721936179e-331.9259299443872359e-323.8518598887744717e-327.703719777548943e-321.5407439555097887e-313.0814879110195774e-316.162975822039155e-311.232595164407831e-302.465190328815662e-304.930380657631324e-309.860761315262648e-301.9721522630525295e-293.944304526105059e-297.888609052210118e-291.5777218104420236e-283.155443620884047e-286.310887241768094e-281.2621774483536189e-272.5243548967072378e-275.0487097934144756e-271.0097419586828951e-262.0194839173657902e-264.0389678347315804e-268.077935669463161e-261.6155871338926322e-253.2311742677852644e-256.462348535570529e-251.2924697071141057e-242.5849394142282115e-245.169878828456423e-241.0339757656912846e-232.0679515313825692e-234.1359030627651384e-238.271806125530277e-231.6543612251060553e-223.3087224502121107e-226.617444900424221e-221.3234889800848443e-212.6469779601696886e-215.293955920339377e-211.0587911840678754e-202.1175823681357508e-204.2351647362715017e-208.470329472543003e-201.6940658945086007e-193.3881317890172014e-196.776263578034403e-191.3552527156068805e-182.710505431213761e-185.421010862427522e-181.0842021724855044e-172.168404344971009e-174.336808689942018e-178.673617379884035e-171.734723475976807e-163.469446951953614e-166.938893903907228e-161.3877787807814457e-152.7755575615628914e-155.551115123125783e-151.1102230246251565e-142.220446049250313e-144.440892098500626e-148.881784197001252e-141.7763568394002505e-133.552713678800501e-137.105427357601002e-131.4210854715202004e-122.8421709430404007e-125.6843418860808015e-121.1368683772161603e-112.2737367544323206e-114.547473508864641e-119.094947017729282e-111.8189894035458565e-103.637978807091713e-107.275957614183426e-101.4551915228366852e-92.9103830456733704e-95.820766091346741e-91.1641532182693481e-82.3283064365386963e-84.6566128730773926e-89.313225746154785e-81.862645149230957e-73.725290298461914e-77.450580596923828e-70.00000149011611938476560.00000298023223876953120.00000596046447753906250.0000119209289550781250.000023841857910156250.00004768371582031250.0000953674316406250.000190734863281250.00038146972656250.0007629394531250.001525878906250.00305175781250.0061035156250.012207031250.02441406250.0488281250.097656250.19531250.3906250.781251.56251.1250.250.5100'
FAILED: Expected: '0', instead got: ''
```

Comment: What is the error message? Hmm ... When dividing a real number  with 2, the result will never go to zero or below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Math.floor()`

Divsion returns `float` when you do `decimal/2`

```js
function binary(decimal) {
  var arr = [];
  var remainderX;
  while (decimal > 0) {
    remainderX = decimal % 2;
    decimal = Math.floor(decimal / 2);
    arr.unshift(remainderX);
  }
  return arr.join('');
}

console.log(binary(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to do what you want:

```
function binary(decimal) {
    return Number(decimal).toString(2);
}
```

Comment: Just making sure in case we get a string from the function call. It's true that it is not mandatory though.

Answer (score 0):

The problems in your code is:

while calculating new decimal  value using the code `decimal = decimal / 2;`, **you are not finding whole number quotient**. Instead **you are trying to divide the decimal number with fraction quotient**, which is incorrect method while converting decimal value to binary value. So you should use `decimal = Math.floor(decimal / 2);` which will return whole number quotient for calculating next decimal value for next iteration.

To test it now, just paste following code in this online java script editor (link : [https://js.do/code/391202][1])

test code :

```
<script>

function binary(decimal) {
    var arr = [];
    var remainderX;
    while (decimal > 0) {
        remainderX = decimal % 2;
        //document.write("fraction quotient = "+decimal / 2+"</br>")
        decimal = Math.floor(decimal / 2);
        //document.write("Whole Number quotient = "+decimal+"</br>")
        arr.unshift(remainderX);
    }
    return arr.join('');
}


binary_vlue = binary(7)
document.write("binary value is = "+binary_vlue)
</script>
```